# What is a generalised solution for the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

I recently read that the system of congruences-

$$x\equiv a_1\pmod {m_1}$$
$$x\equiv a_2\pmod {m_2}$$$$x\equiv a_3\pmod {m_3}$$...$$x\equiv a_k\pmod {m_k}$$

has a solution given by $$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{m}{m_i}a_i\alpha_i$$

where $m=\prod_{i=1}^k m_i$ and $\alpha$ is a solution ie.$\alpha_1\equiv a_i\pmod{m_i}$.

But,I am having problem in understanding what changes will come up in the solution if I replace the $x$'s in the coefficient to $b_1x$,$b_2x$...$b_kx$ ie if I change the equations into-

$$b_1x\equiv a_1\pmod {m_1}$$$$b_2x\equiv a_1\pmod {m_1}$$...$$b_kx\equiv a_1\pmod {m_1}$$

How will the solution change now?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I think the generalized solution is assuming the $m_i$ are relatively prime?

Comment: Did you want $b_ix\equiv a_i\pmod{m_i}$? Or did you really want $a_1$ and $b_1$ in all the equations?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your condition on the $\alpha_i$. The usual conditions would be $\alpha_i\equiv \delta_{ij}\pmod{m_i}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta. Alternatively, the conditon in the $\alpha_i$ should be that $\sum \frac{m}{m_i}\alpha_i = 1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, $bx\equiv a\pmod m$ (when it can be solved) is equivalent to $x\equiv c\pmod {m'}$ for some $c$ and some $m'\mid m$. So it reduces to the first case if there is a solution. If $b$ and $m$ are relatively prime, then $c=ay$ and $m'=m$, where $mx+by=1$.

If $b_i$ is relatively prime to $m_i$ for all $i$, and the $m_i$ are pairwise relatively prime, then show that $m,\frac{mb_1}{m_1},\frac{mb_2}{m_2},\dots,\frac{mb_k}{m_k}$ are relatively prime, and then solve:

$$m\alpha_0+\sum \frac{mb_i}{m_i}\alpha_i = 1$$

Then let $$x=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{m}{m_i}a_i\alpha_i.$$

Then $$b_ix\equiv \sum_j\frac{mb_i}{m_j}a_j\alpha_i\equiv a_i\frac{mb_i}{m_i}\alpha\equiv a_i\pmod{m_i}$$

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you meant

\begin{align}
   b_1x &\equiv a_1 \pmod{m_1} \\
   b_2x &\equiv a_2 \pmod{m_2} \\
   &\phantom{n}\vdots \\
   b_kx &\equiv a_k \pmod {m_k}
\end{align}

If that is what you meant, then you can write

\begin{align}
   x &\equiv b_1^{-1}a_1 \pmod{m_1} \\
   x &\equiv b_2^{-1}a_2 \pmod{m_2} \\
   &\phantom{n}\vdots \\
   x &\equiv b_k^{-1}a_k \pmod {m_k}
\end{align}

and then your solution is 
$$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{m}{m_i}b_i^{-1}a_i\alpha_i$$